# nonReentrant modifier on mint method

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ether, erc-721

Is `_safeMint()` of ERC721 safe from re-entrancy attack? Is nonReentrant modifier should be used with `safeMint()`

Answer (score 0):

The internal function is not at risk because an external contract cannot call it, but if it's expossed in a public or external function, it should have a reentrancy guard because an external contract could call that over and over again, like in this known attack: https://blocksecteam.medium.com/when-safemint-becomes-unsafe-lessons-from-the-hypebears-security-incident-2965209bda2a